# Query based on a form with multiple criteria in one text field

Tags: ms-access

I am fairly new to access and I am working on a database to manage Bills of Materials (BOMs) of several products. I would like to create a form where the user can input a list of component names to see where these components are being used.

To run a query based on one word is simple but I am struggling to extend it to more than one word. 
I would like the user to input the components separated by new lines like this:

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
...
```

If I use the text field as is then the query won't find anything because it takes the text field as a whole and not line by line.

I have tried to process the text field into a ListBox because I thought that it would be handled like an array but it does not have a `<value>` therefore it will not return any search results.

My next try was to use a second text field where I can format the information to the format `"Item1";"Item2";"Item3"` so that I can use it in an `in` statement.

If I directly put:

`in ("Item1";"Item2";"Item3")`

In the query criteria then it will run as expected, however if I try to reference the `HelpText` (which contains: `"Item1";"Item2";"Item3"`) like so:

`In ([Forms]![Search_mult_component]![HelpText])`

Then I get no results. I have also tried formatting the text to include the parenthesis like so `("Item1";"Item2";"Item3")`

As I mentinoed I am just getting to know Access therefore I am not sure if this is a good practice or if I am trying to force something which can be done in a simple way with a slightly different approach.

Thank you for the support in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve it after @Lee Mac provided the spark!
I created a Table `TempTable` to store the input values and I was able to use this table in the query later. It still took some code to get there though!
In the form I used a textbox with the multiline data as defined in the question and a button to run the Query. The steps therefore are somewhat separated between the Textbox itself and the button.
The Textbox has the following code for the `AfterUpdate` event:

```
Private Sub search_text_AfterUpdate()
Dim TempTable As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim allNums() As String

' ======= Open table =======
Set TempTable = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [TempTable]")

' ======= Clear table =======
DoCmd.SetWarnings False                 'Disable warnings. If not disabled the user will be prompted to confirm the delete
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM TempTable"  'SQL statement used to delete all entries from a table
DoCmd.SetWarnings True                  'Enable warnings

' ======= Process multiline text =======
allNums = Split(search_text.Value, vbNewLine)                       'Split the multiline text

For i = LBound(allNums) To UBound(allNums)                          'process line by line
      If (StrComp(Trim(allNums(i)), "", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then    'Check if current text is empty string
          TempTable.AddNew                                          'Add new Record to table
          TempTable![ToSearch] = (Trim(allNums(i)))                 'Fill in the text, trim whitespaces
          TempTable.Update                                          'Update Table. Seems to be necessary for changes to take effect
      End If
Next i

' ======= Clean up and close table =======
TempTable.Close                                                     'Close the table

Set TempTable = Nothing                                             'No idea why this is needed :D

' ======= Refresh table =======
'DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, "TempTable"
'DoCmd.Requery
'DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataTable, "TempTable", acLast

End Sub
```

This code takes care of clearing the table `TempTable`and filling it with the new input. `TempTable` has two columns `ID` and `ToSearch` where `ID` is the primary key for the table and `ToSearch` will be populated with the input from the textbox. I have seen during the testing that when the entries from the table get deleted the new items will still receive new keys when added which worries me because the keys might run out at some point. This is a problem for the future but if you have any advice on this (for example removing the key from the table or sthing) then please let me know.
The code runs after the user hits an enter on the text field but needs a `Requery` of the table to take effect! This is included in the Button macro:
First the table oject is selected and a Requery is run. After this I close the table and open the actual Query which also needs to be requeried to show the correct updated values.
With this solution I was able to do what I intended to do without having to delve into the depths of SQL.
As always, I appreciate your comments!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Just like table and field names, the value string of an IN statement must be present before the query runs.

Your only option is to write the SQL string dynamically and, say, create a temporary query to which you pass the SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  
It might be nitpicking but the `in` statement would be finished before the query runs since the text field is finished before the query is rerun. Or it has to be finished during the "design"?  
How should I go about the SQL? Do I need to pre-process the string to an "array-like" format before or I can do all that in the SQL?

Comment: To put it differently: The IN statement must be literal to be valid. Or "ready to use" if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Using a list box to represent the selection criteria is a good approach as it will allow the user to select & manipulate multiple items as distinct elements, without having to worry about delimiters and such.

However, rather than attempting to access the *value* of the list box, I would suggest using the list box to populate an underlying table, which you can then join to the relevant field in your query, causing the results to be automatically filtered without the need for a `where` clause.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
Can you elaborate on

"to populate an underlying table, which you can then join to the relevant field in your query" 

This sounds like a possible solution but I don't quite know how to go about it. Would you use a sub-query where the content of a column would be filled based on the user input? Do you have any examples?
Thank you!